# Откуда в эмуляторе берется время UTC?

Tags: android, эмулятор, android-emulator

У себя в приложении я использую время utc для проверки протухлости токена. Все работает прекрасно, но меня интересует вопрос - откуда берется на эмуляторе это время. Я использую Genymotion для тестирования приложения. У меня лично было два варианта - либо эмулятор подключается к какому-то своему сервису в сети, и тянет время себе, либо есть второй вариант - и он по-моему не очень правильный: эмулятор тянет время с пк, но я не могу понять откуда, ведь у винды в основе вроде не линукс ядро, либо я чего-то не понимаю.

Comment: А что мешает эмулятору преобразовать виндовое время в юникс-время или utc?

Comment: я честно говоря не знаю просто как это вообще происходит, берет время откуда то и все)) у меня часто возникал этот вопрос, но  я так и не смог на него ответить)

Comment: В настройках винды выбирается часовой пояс, получить из локального времени utc - элементарная задача уровня школьной арифметики